# Constructing all compact Hausdorff spaces from a generalised sequential-limit operator

Tags: general-topology

Given a set $X$ and a *partial* function $\lim:X^{\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow X$, define for all $M\subset X$, $$\overline{M}=\{x\in X :\forall (x_n)_{\mathbb{N}}\in M^{\mathbb{N}}\,((x_n)_{\mathbb{N}},x)\in \lim \Rightarrow x\in M \}.$$ Now, suppose $\lim$ is such that the following are satisfied:

1. $\overline{\overline{L}\cup \overline{M}}=\overline{L}\cup \overline{M}$
2. $\overline{\displaystyle\bigcap_{i\in I}\overline{L_i}}=\displaystyle\bigcap_{i\in I}\overline{L_i}$

Is it possible to define a compact Hausdorff space $X$, using $\lim$ in the obvious way?

---

The same as above but for a relation $\operatorname{clust}:X^{\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow X$ and claiming a general definition for a compact space?

Comment: I recommend wiki for this matter.

Comment: So you want the $\overline{M}$ to be a closure operation, and you get your topology from that, and you ask if the condition you state is equivalent to this topology being Hausdorff?

Comment: @Amitai Yuval: Thanks for the tips, but I couldn't find the proof there.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: I don't think it's possible to prove that it's a closure operation if (i) and (ii) is not included..?

Comment: Possibly, I don't actually know much about defining topologies from closure operations. But as stated, the question does not really make sense, as you specify a set and a function, and ask about something which is a property of sets with a topology (you did not specify a topology).

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: You're right, I will clearify.

Comment: Something like this works for *compact* Hausdorff spaces, but it is necessary to work with arbitrarily large index sets and to consider limits of ultrafilters and not just sequences. The keyword here is "ultrafilter monad." Your proposal can't work as stated because in general topologies are not determined by convergence of sequences; one needs more general objects such as (ultra)filters or nets.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: I see. There must be something more general than the ordered set of natural numbers. What about the index for the unions in (ii)?

Comment: (1) Your definition of $\overline{M}$ has me quite confused. I would have thought that $\overline{M}$ is the set of all $\lim ( (x_n)_\mathbb{N} )$ where $(x_n)_\mathbb{N} \in M^\mathbb{N}$. (Something like $\{ x : ( \exists (x_n)_\mathbb{N} \in M^\mathbb{N} ) ( \lim ( (x_n)_\mathbb{N} ) = x ) \}$.) (2) To even get started, you will probably have to make some assumptions on the $\lim$ partial function to even start to make sense of this. (For example, constant sequences should converge to their constant value.) As it stands, $\overline{M}$ may not even be a superset of $M$.

Comment: @Arthur Fischer: You are right. It was more complicated than I relalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question in the post is "No" as can be seen by the following simple example. Let $X := \mathbb{N}$ and let $lim \subseteq (\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N})$ be defined by

$((x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}, x) \in lim :\Leftrightarrow (\exists N_0\in \mathbb{N})[k\geq N_0 \implies x_k = x].$

Then $\overline{M}=M$ for all $M\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, therefore the topology you get on $\mathbb{N}$ is the discrete topology which is not compact.

Comment: It seems as I should have asked something like: which class of topological spaces can be defined ... etc? If any? :)